# Curl request without refreshing the catcha image

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, phpunit

I have a cURL script to getting the page html and form elements, after getting the html my second cURL script fired for auto submission the html form. written as follows
Problem is that when i got html. the html has a captcha image and when i submissing the form through second cURL script the captcha image is refreshing or change. in this case my form not submitting.

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com");
$data = "&fname=example&email=user@website.com&country=us&captcha=qwerty";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
  "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_exec($ch);
```